# Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen v5 does not send the headers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

Trying to set up a swagger, and I need to pass two header values. One is the bearer token, and the other one is a tenant id. For some reason, I don't get back the values I put in the Authentication form.

Here is my code but not sure if it is not properly configured or something not working as expected from Swagger.

```
internal static IServiceCollection AddSwagger(this IServiceCollection collection)
{
    collection.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
    {
        options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
        {
            Title = "Title",
            Version = "v1",
            Description = "Description v1."
        });

        options.AddSecurityDefinition("Authorization", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Name = "Authorization",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
            Scheme = "bearer",
            BearerFormat = "JWT"
        });

        options.AddSecurityDefinition("x-client-accessId", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Name = "x-client-accessId",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
            Scheme = "apiKey",
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
        });

        options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
        {
            [new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Name = "Authorization",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
                Scheme = "bearer",
                BearerFormat = "JWT"
            }] = new List<string>() 
        });

        options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
        {
            [new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Name = "x-client-accessId",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Scheme = "apiKey",
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
            }] = new List<string>() 
        });
    });

    return collection;
}
```

Configure method:

```
app.UseRouting();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseSwagger();

app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Swagger Movies Demo V1");
    c.DisplayRequestDuration();
});

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute(); });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the below code in the `Configure` method also.

```
// Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint
app.UseSwagger(c => { c.RouteTemplate = "swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json"; });

// Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui assets (HTML, JS, CSS etc.)
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
    options.SwaggerEndpoint($"../swagger/{_apiVersion}/swagger.json", $"MyProject API v1");
    options.DisplayRequestDuration(); // Controls the display of the request duration (in milliseconds) for "Try it out" requests.  
});
```

Comment: Hi @vivek, I already have a similar code in my configure method. Check my edited question.

Comment: So what’s the issue? Are you facing, can you please make it clear

Comment: The problem is that even if I supply both header values from the swagger page, still when I submit one random api, I dont get those headers on backend side.